# Не работает сервлет

Tags: java, servlet, maven

Создал проект **maven** *webapp* в консоли,
прописал зависимости в `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>      
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

описание сервлета в web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-mapping>
<url-pattern>/<url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

сам сервлет

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
    pw.println("<h1> Hello Servlets!!!</h1>"); 

}

}
```

собрал проект `mvn clean package`, залил на **tomcat** папка `webapps`

Захожу в браузере `localhost:8080/webApp/` на выходе ноль.

---

Вот структура моего проекта после сборки. 
Я специально все делаю из консоли что бы разобраться что откуда и куда....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Для форматирования кода внутри строки есть удобный синтаксис — ` с обеих сторон.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` или `http://localhost:8080/Servlet`

Comment: К сожалению не работает

Comment: `packaging` установлен в `war`? Какое полное имя полученного архива?

Comment: Меня всё еще смущает разница между пакетжами в которых лежит ваш класс после компиляции с тем, где он находится до. Может вы в начале класса указали пакетж и забыли нам это написать? Если так, то у вас видимо неправильное объявление сервлета. В любом случае, попробуйте в объявление сервлета добавить `<servlet-class>com.myapps.test.Servlet</servlet-class>`

Answer (score 1):

Вот код простейшего тестового сервлета.

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>learning-servlet</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**src/main/java/Servlet.java:**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
            writer.println("<h1 align='center'>Hello! I'm servlet!</h1>");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Сборка командой `mvn package`. Далее копируется в `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`.

Открывается по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:8080/learning-servlet`